# AgGrid: Show or Hide column based on row grouped level opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using Ag grid enterprise and have row grouped based on some hierarchy and we are using SSRM, so when the user would click on any grouped row, an **API** call would be made to fetch its below hierarchy.

We have a requirement to add a column only when the user is able to view the data of a particular hierarchy and hide that column if the user can't see the data because they collapsed any of its parent row.

For example: Let's suppose our Hierarchy is `Planet -> Continent -> Country -> State -> District`
So we need to add a column Pin Code only when any of the States are clicked and we can see all the District under it. Also we need to hide that column when the user collapse the row group from any of its parent (meaning, all the Districts would be closes if any of its parent State, Country, Continent or Planet is clicked.

Can someone please help here how I can achieve it?

I tried using `onGroupExpandOrCollapse` but was not able to comprehend how to achieve it.
If someone could help?

Comment: Hi @Soumya Sharma, was not able to get what are you looking for, but from whatever I have understood, this might be helpful https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-custom-group-columns/ , if you are still facing challenges please add code pen for the same, so we could help you better

Comment: Hi @AbhijeetAbnave, yes, the use case is similar to the example shown. It's just that we need to hide that column until the user expands a row which has data for that particular column. And we are using server side row model so it's getting a bit tricky to use your provided example as it's for client side.